# Running script on my local computer when jobs submitted by qsub on a server finish

Tags: bash, qsub

I am submitting jobs via qsub to a server, and then want to analyze the results on the local machine after jobs are finished. Though I can find a way to submit the analysis job on the server, but don't know how to run that script on my local machine.

```
jobID=$(qsub job.sh)

qsub -W depend=afterok:$jobID analyze.sh
```

But instead of the above, I want something like

```
if(qsub -W depend=afterok:$jobID) finished successfully
sh analyze.sh
else
some script
```

How can I accomplish the above task?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a similar issue and I'll try to sketch the solution that worked for me:

After submitting your actual job,

jobID=$(qsub job.sh)

I would create a loop in your script that checks if the job is still running using

```
qstat $jobID | grep $jobID | awk '{print $5}'
```

Although I'm not 100% sure if the status is in the 5h column, you better double check. While the job is idling, the status will be `I` or `Q`, while running `R`, and afterwards `C`.

Once it's finished, I usually grep the output files for signs that the run was a success or not, and then run the appropriate post-processing script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is really useful, though a few clarifications would be awesome.
1. Shouldn't it be simply, as $jobID is not an array right?
    qstat $jobID | awk '{print $5}'
2. I should use a sleep command to create a loop and to check periodically the status of job? If the job is finished while the loop is not checking, it will later say "job not found".
3. Column 5 is correct, and while in queue, the output is "Time-Q", printed vertically. How do I access that Q part. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @prabhat 1. No, it's not because it's an array, bit because usually the output of `qstat` is multiple lines, with column headers etc, and you want to parse only the correct line. 2. Use a sleep time of less than 60 seconds - usually completed jobs are listed much longer than this before they disappear. 3. Hm. Could you please add the full output of `qstat` to your question?

Comment: Thanks Michael for the clarifications. The corresponding outputs are

    'qstat 36749
Job id                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
36749.cell0               job400.sh        prabhatshankar         0 Q default'


    'qstat 36749 | awk '{print $5}'
Time
-
Q'

Comment: See, that's why you need the `grep`. If you put it in, you'll get only the `Q`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that works for me is to use qsub synchronous with the option

```
qsub -sync y job.sh
```

(either on command line or as

```
#$ -sync y
```

in the script (job.sh) itself.

qsub will then exit with code 0 only if the job (or all array jobs) have finished successfully.